# How to solve Fatal Error: Index out of range error in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

In this piece of code, when the iteration position reach 13 out of an array with 20 elements, it crashes with the index out of range error.

```
let counterHeaders = headers.count
for value in 0..<(counterHeaders){
    if headers[value] == "" {
        headers.remove(at: value)
    }
}
```

---

Note: counterHeaders variable was created to check how many values was in headers array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to iterate your `indices` in reverse order when removing items in your collection.

```
for value in headers.indices.reversed() {
    if headers[value] == "" {
        headers.remove(at: value)
    }
}
```

Note also there is a mutating method that accepts a predicate called `removeAll(where:)`:

```
headers.removeAll(where: \.isEmpty)
```